# Can you use a firepit on Deal beach

Tags: fire, beach

My question was more around a specific beach, Deal, Kent to be exact. Can you have and use a fire pit in the evening on the public beach around a few drinks that would be carefully monitored?

Comment: Connected question, not really a duplicate in my view: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1329/is-it-legal-to-light-bonfires-on-uk-beaches

Comment: Nearby Thanet District has a number of byelaws relating to bonfires and barbeques on the beaches, shown [here](https://www.thanet.gov.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Foreshore-Info-Booklet-A5.pdf). But Deal is in Dover District and I can't find any relevant info on the [Dover District website](https://www.dover.gov.uk/Home.aspx), though it is possible they have similar laws.